# Wpf WebView show blank white window when opening a local pdf file

Tags: c#, wpf, webview

I am trying to open a local pdf file into `webview` but get a blank white window. I have tried different solutions but it didn't work. I am getting the project parent directory path in `DirectoryPath` and then replacing `\` with `/` and then appending my folder and file path `/Invoices/img.pdf.`

```
private void PdfViewWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string DirectoryPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent?.FullName;
    string dp = DirectoryPath.Replace(@"\" , "/");

    PdfWebView.Navigate(@"file:///" + dp + @"/Invoices/img.pdf");
}
```